# unzip is returning exit code 1 even if the extraction was successful

Tags: linux, unzip, exit-code

I have a zip file which is compressed on a windows server and has the windows directory structure.

I am trying to uncompress the file on an ubuntu server with the command:

```
/tmp/temp » unzip -d /tmp/temp/temp backup.zip
```

The unzipping works fine, the directory structure is converted into a Linux based one automatically. But due to some reason whatsoever the exit code of the extract command is 1 and this is messing up my Jenkins job, which is not proceeding further.

```
  inflating: /tmp/temp/temp/fs/site/wwwroot/vendor-a2341eb904.js  
  inflating: /tmp/temp/temp/fs/site/wwwroot/vendor-fc433e18b6.css  
  inflating: /tmp/temp/temp/fs/site/wwwroot/web.config  
  inflating: /tmp/temp/temp/meta     
------------------------------------------------------------
/tmp/temp » echo $?                                                                                                                                                
1
```

I even tested the archive to compare the CRC of the extracted file with the one in the archive and it seems to be allright:

```
    testing: fs\site\wwwroot\vendor-fc433e18b6.css   OK
    testing: fs\site\wwwroot\web.config   OK
    testing: meta                     OK
No errors detected in compressed data of backup.zip.
------------------------------------------------------------
/tmp/temp » echo $?                                                                                                                                               
0
```

Any idea what might be the cause of return code 1 in the unzip command?

BTW: I also tried to `set +e` in my jenkins job to disregard the exit codes, but that didn't do any help.

Comment: The main purpose of exit codes is to be able to use these utilities in a script or external program that performs with error checking. I don't see how that is off-topic to programming and development.

Comment: This link provides related workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721876/make-unzip-try-to-unzip-files-if-they-exist-without-failure-if-not

Answer (score 4):

Check with `-v` option if any file has been skipped

The [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) page for unzip states following for return value `1`

> one or more warning errors were encountered, but processing completed
>   successfully anyway. This includes zipfiles where one or more files
>   was skipped due to unsupported compression method or encryption with
>   an unknown password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue and it is causing your shell script to end abruptly without errors, Check if your shell script file has `set -e` command at the top.

Set -e will end your script if any errors are thrown by any of the executing lines.

Unzip exit with error code in many scenarios even when there exist a non-critical warning and unzipping is successful.