# How to read in variables from multi-line file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to read from a file that is multiple lines with multiple variables per line. There are four variables: item, price, max_qty, and min_qty. The file looks like this:

```
item price
min_qty max_qty
```

I have tried:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r first second third fourth; do
    echo "$first $second $third $fourth
done
```

This does not work. I want the output to be:

```
item price min_qty max_qty
```

I have also thought about somehow replacing the new lines with spaces and then reading from that line. I don't want to actually change the file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` twice:

```
while read -r first second && read -r third fourth; do 
  echo "$first $second $third $fourth"
done < file
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Can you explain why using read twice works? I had tried before using read twice, but on two lines (not &&). It just read from the beginning of the file twice.

Comment: @rrfeva it works because each `read ` call reads one line from input.

Answer (score 0):

If it is true that "the file looks like this" (two lines, two values per line, not a larger file with many pairs of lines like that), then you can do it with a single `read` by using the `-d` option to set the line delimiter to empty:

```
read -r -d '' first second third fourth <file
echo "$first $second $third $fourth"
```

- The code prints 'item price min_qty max_qty' with the example file.
- If you have `errexit` or the `ERR` trap set, the program will exit immediately, and silently, immediately after the `read` is executed.  See [Bash ignoring error for a particular command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11231937/4154375) for ways of avoiding that.
- The code will work with the default value of `IFS` (space+tab+newline).  If IFS could be set to something different elsewhere in the program, set it explicitly with `IFS=$' \t\n' read -r -d '' ...`.
- The code will continue to work if you change the file format (all values on one line, one value per line, ...), assuming that it still contains only four values.
- The code won't work if the file actually contains many line pairs.  In that case the ["read twice"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55693005/4154375) solution by [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) is good.