# Failed Cypress test exit in 'bash exited with code 1' in Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, azure-devops, cypress

I have setup my Cypress tests to run in Azure DevOps.  I run the test via CMD command in my yml file and then get the test results.  When the tests pass everything is working as expected and the test results show up in the summary.  When the a test fails the CMD steps fails with the error ##[error]Bash exited with code '1' and the test results are not populated.  Is there a way the bash exit with 0 on failed tests as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask bash to ignore the error like this

```
my-test-script || true
```

See answer [Bash ignoring error for a particular command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231937/bash-ignoring-error-for-a-particular-command)