# How can I program a loop so that it does not stop upon failure?

Tags: bash

I have a loop that is doing a GPG verification, serially. When it gets to a failure however, it exits the loop. How can I program this loop so that it does not?

Currently I have:

```
while read -r line;
gpg --verify $line
do 
  if gpg --verify $line; then
   echo "success";
  else 
   echo "failed gpg check";
  fi
done < gpg_verify.txt
```

I want the failure to be acknowledged but I don't want it to stop.

Comment: Maybe this SO question will help. [Bash ignoring error for a particular command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231937/bash-ignoring-error-for-a-particular-command)

Comment: which of the two `gpg` calls is failing?  what happens if you remove the  `gpg --verify $line` that's between the 'while` and `do` clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the verification to decide when to exit the loop. Also, [fix your quoting.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```sh
while read -r line
do 
  if gpg --verify "$line"; then
   echo "success";
  else 
   echo "failed gpg check";
  fi
done < gpg_verify.txt
```

Just to spell this out, `while x; y` stops whenever `y` fails, and won't stop when `x` fails. Perhaps you meant `while x && y` but here, just put `y` inside the loop if that's what you actually want.