# How to avoid No such file or directory in linux

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, chmod

I am trying to chmod into a file. Sometimes it doesn't exist. In a case like this, I want it not to give any error. **That means the `chmod` should only be executed if the file is exist.**

I am doing this with `gitlab-runner`, but still it executes the `shell` scripts so this is something to be fixed from `linux` side, not from `gitlab`

Here is what I try to do

```
ssh-publickey:
  stage: ssh-publickey
  script: 
    - pwd
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh # i want to check before executing this command
    - sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh/gitlab.pem
    - echo $PRIVATEKEY > ~/.ssh/gitlab.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the chmod flag *-f* to ignore errors i.e. don't print an error message if the file does not exist. However, the command will still have an exit status of *1* as it did not find a file. If you want to avoid that and always get a status code of *0* even if the file does not exist, you could do the following:

```
chmod -f 700 ~/.ssh | :
```

The ":" is the linux null-command, which will exit with code 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap the chmod command in an if statement to check if the file/directory exists before running it:

if [ -d ~/.ssh ] ; then chmod 0700 ~/.ssh ; fi

Answer (score 0):

Add `|| true` add the end of the command

so in your case:

```
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh || true
```

will ignore any error

[Bash ignoring error for a particular command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231937/bash-ignoring-error-for-a-particular-command)