# Is there a way to toggle the "set -e" option on a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that I want to fail on any errors for one section of the code, but continue through errors in another.

I know 'set -e' will achieve the first requirement, but is there anyway to 'unset -e' for a script, or ignore errors for a specific line or function?

Comment: just `set +e` before that line and then `set -e` again

Comment: `set -e` is somewhat controversial => https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Pedantic note: you aren't toggling the setting; you want to explicitly disable it, then explicitly enable it. (Toggling *always* changes the setting; `set -e` doesn't change anything if `errexit` is already enabled. You can toggle an unknown setting and know that whatever the setting *was*, the opposite is now true, even if you still don't know what the new setting is.)

Comment: See [Bash ignoring error for a particular command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11231937/4154375).

Answer (score 7):

`set -e` to enable and `set +e` to disable.

But if you only want to ignore errors for a single line, consume the exit code of the command on that line:

```
! failing_command
```

or

```
failing_command || :
```