# Bash "not": inverting the exit status of a command

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I know I can do this...

```
if diff -q $f1 $f2
then
    echo "they're the same"
else
    echo "they're different"
fi
```

But what if I want to negate the condition that I'm checking? i.e. something like this (which obviously doesn't work)

```
if not diff -q $f1 $f2
then
    echo "they're different"
else
    echo "they're the same"
fi
```

I could do something like this...

```
diff -q $f1 $f2
if [[ $? > 0 ]]
then
    echo "they're different"
else
    echo "they're the same"
fi
```

Where I check whether the exit status of the previous command is greater than 0. But this feels a bit awkward. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: The canonical may be *[How can I negate the return-value of a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367069/)*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if ! diff -q "$f1" "$f2"; then ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to negate, you are looking for `!` :

```
if ! diff -q $f1 $f2; then
    echo "they're different"
else
    echo "they're the same"
fi
```

or (simplty reverse the if/else actions) :

```
if diff -q $f1 $f2; then
    echo "they're the same"
else
    echo "they're different"
fi
```

Or also, try doing this using `cmp` :

```
if cmp &>/dev/null $f1 $f2; then
    echo "$f1 $f2 are the same"
else
    echo >&2 "$f1 $f2 are NOT the same"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To negate use `if ! diff -q $f1 $f2;`. Documented in `man test`:

```
! EXPRESSION
      EXPRESSION is false
```

Not quite sure why you need the negation, as you handle both cases... If you only need to handle the case where they don't match:

```
diff -q $f1 $f2 || echo "they're different"
```

Comment: Is this actually invoking test though? I'm not using "test" nor "[".

Comment: It's not invoking it, it's a shell builtin (for performance reasons), but the syntax is the same

Comment: `man test` is irrelevant here. From `man bash`: 
_ If  the  reserved word  !   precedes  a  pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of the exit status as described above._