# Negate a command return value condition in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I tried to negate the following condition:

```
if pgrep "$NAME" >> /dev/null; then
    # stuff
fi
```

At first I tried a syntax, what you can found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367069/how-can-i-negate-the-return-value-of-a-process).

```
if ! [[ pgrep "$NAME" >> /dev/null ]]; then
    # stuff
fi
```

While this syntax is perfect if you want to compare variables and literals, however in my case it will fail with the following error:

watchdog: line 58: conditional binary operator expected

watchdog: line 58: syntax error near `"$NAME"'

watchdog: line 58: `    if ! [[ pgrep "$NAME" >> /dev/null ]]; then'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `!` to to check if it failed:

```
if ! pgrep "$NAME" >> /dev/null; then
    # stuff
fi
```