# What's the meaning of a ! before a command in the shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

What is the purpose of a shell command (part of a shell script) starting with an exclamation mark?

Concrete example:

**In foo.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
! docker stop foo
! docker rm -f foo
# ... other stuff
```

I know that without the space the exclamation mark is used for history replacements and `! <expression>` according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) can be used to evaluate "*True if expr is false*". But in the example context that does not make sense to me.

Comment: If the return code (visible as `$?`) was 0 (success) it flips it to 1, if the return code was a failure (non-zero) it flips it to 0 (zero).  Maybe these commands are expected to fail and you have `-e` set or `set -o errexit`?  Whatever, this is a case where comments should have been added.

Comment: @cdarke `set -e` ignores commands whose exit statuses are explicitly negated with `!`.

Comment: Related: [Elaboration of "!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367069/how-can-i-negate-the-return-value-of-a-process/367167#367167).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

TL;DR: This is just by-passing the `set -e` flag in the specific line where you are using it.

---

Adding add to [hek2mgl's correct and useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261761/1983854).

You have:

```
set -e
! command
```

[Bash Reference Manual → Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) describes:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell. The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline (...). **If the reserved word ‘!’ precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status** as described above. The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

This means that `!` preceding a command is negating the exit status of it:

```
$ echo 23
23
$ echo $?
0
                # But
$ ! echo 23
23
$ echo $?
1
```

Or:

```
$ echo 23 && echo "true" || echo "fail"
23
true
$ ! echo 23 && echo "true" || echo "fail"
23
fail
```

The exit status is useful in many ways. In your script, used together with `set -e` makes the script exit whenever a command returns a non-zero status.

Thus, when you have:

```
set -e
command1
command2
```

If `command1` returns a non-zero status, the script will finish and won't proceed to `command2`.

However, there is also an interesting point to mention, described in [4.3.1 The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> **-e**
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status. **The shell does not exit** if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or **if the command’s return status is being inverted with !**. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.

---

Taking all of these into consideration, when you have:

```
set -e
! command1
command2
```

What you are doing is to by-pass the `set -e` flag in the `command1`. Why?

- if `command1` runs properly, it will return a zero status. `!` will negate it, but `set -e` won't trigger an exit by the because it comes from a return status inverted with !, as described above.
- if `command1` fails, it will return a non-zero status. `!` will negate it, so the line will end up returning a zero status and the script will continue normally.

Comment: so with `set -e`, it means **no error allowed** in the script, but with a leading **`!`**, it marks an exception meaning this command is fine to fail.

Comment: @ryenus Not really. `!` simply negates the exit status of a command. It is just one of the many exceptions in the list of commands whose exit status `set -e` will ignore.

Comment: @chepner: I'm not sure why you say "Not really.". ryenus's comment is correct.

Comment: @ryenus Yes, I have. `!` negates the exit status of a command whether or not the `-e` option is in effect. It does not simply mark a command as an exception to the `-e` option.

Comment: @chpner, `!` alone indeed negates the command exit status, regardless `set -e` is set or not. But here the gist is about the **side effect of `!` in the context of `set -e`**, which doesn't fail the script even if the command succeeded. Without such side effect. the script would fail when the exit status of a succeeded command is negated by `!`.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want the script to fail in both cases, error or success of the command, you can also use this alternative:

```
set -e
docker stop foo || true
```

The boolean *or true* makes the pipeline always have `0` as the return value.

Comment: `man bash` says _If the reserved word ! precedes a pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of the exit status_. Wouldn't this mean that if the command executes successfully, it would trigger an error since it negates a True?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using the `!`

Comment: @fedorqui I expected the same, but when I try it with a simple demo script it doesn't terminate when the command is successful. e.g. `set -e\n! echo "I am okay"\n\echo "done"` runs through. `set -e\n! give_me_an_error\n\echo "done"` also runs through (this is what is described in the answer). So, at least in my shell (zsh on macOS) it is lenient towards errors and does not interfere with successful `exit 0` commands.

Comment: @sthzg OK I found it. From [Bash Reference Manual → 4.3.1 The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) on `-e`: _The shell does not exit if (...) the command’s return status is being inverted with !_.

Comment: @fedorqui Good catch and good to know! I recommend to put that into an answer

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing because it doesn't directly explain what the difference is between `! command` and `! command || true`.  That is, it should state that the exclamation mark "instead means fail if the command succeeds".  Without it, the reference to "both cases" is also confusing (it wasn't clear on my first reading that "error or success" was meant to be a parenthetical element and not part of a comma-separated list.

Comment: Sorry, "both cases"? One case is "when the command fails" -- what's the other one? Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: @jamesdlin, the exclamation mark doesn't mean "instead means fail if the command succeeds" as far as `set -e` is concerned. It does invert the resulting value of `$?`, of course.

Comment: @ilkkachu I meant to suggest *adding* that remark in addition the existing remark of "don't fail the script when the command fails.".  Either statement *by itself* is insufficient to explain the behavior.

Comment: @jamesdlin, yes, and I would suggest _not adding_ such a remark, for the simple reason that it isn't true.