# Do not abort script if a specific command fails

Tags: bash

I am running my scripts with:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
```

Which aborts the script whenever a problem occurs, as wanted. But sometimes I expect one of the commands to eventually fail, and I would like to tell `bash` to ignore the fail condition. In `make` you can ignore the status of one command with the handy:

```
-command
```

Is there something similar in `bash`? The only thing that comes to mind is the ugly:

```
set +e
command
set -e
```

Answer (score 10):

You could just do a no-op on the command failure or set an explicit true condition as

```
command || true
```

or for no-op as

```
command || :
```

Doing so forces the command-list (even a pipeline) to return an exit status of 0 on failure. See

```
true | false
echo $?
1
true | false || true
echo $?
0
true | false || :
echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 5):

Just prepend a `!` to the command so that its exit status does not make the script exit when running it with `e`:

```
! command
```

As seen in [What's the meaning of a ! before a command in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47261313/1983854), having `! command` negates the exit status of the given command and, used with `set -e`, prevents the shell to exit whatever the exit result is on that line.

From [Bash Reference Manual → Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell. The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline (...). **If the reserved word ‘!’ precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status** as described above. The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

Then we have the info about [4.3.1 The `set` Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> **-e**
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status. **The shell does not exit** if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or **if the command’s return status is being inverted with !**.

All together, and quoting my own answer:

> When you have:
>
> ```
> set -e
> ! command1
> command2
> ```
>
> What you are doing is to by-pass the `set -e` flag in the `command1`.
>   Why?
>
> - if `command1` runs properly, it will return a zero status. `!` will negate it, but `set -e` won't trigger an exit by the because it comes
>     from a return status inverted with !, as described above.
> - if `command1` fails, it will return a non-zero status. `!` will negate it, so the line will end up returning a zero status and the
>     script will continue normally.

Comment: This is the cleanest syntax. It is not intuitive because the reasons behind this are quite complex, but the syntax is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is

Could just write your own function though

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

-(){
set +e
"$@"
set -e
}

- command

echo got here
```

May want to use a function name since `-` is already used in bash.

As chepner pointed out it only works for simple commands, though, not pipelines or lists.

Comment: That only works for simple commands, though, not pipelines or lists.

Comment: @chepner Thats true.