# How to invert a condition in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if a directory exists on Android.

From [an answer to *Check if a file exists with a wildcard in a shell script*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-a-wildcard-in-a-shell-script/6364244#6364244), I get an idea. So I use [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)) like below.

```
if [ adb shell ls ${test_dir}  2> /dev/null ] ;
then
   echo "files exist"
else
   echo "files do not exist"

fi
```

I am new to Bash scripting. I know `adb shell ls` will return all file names. But what's meaning of `2> /dev/null`?

**And I only care about `files do not exist` condition. So how do I  invert the condition?**

#### Second version

```
if [ ! adb shell ls ${test_dir}  2> /dev/null ] ;
then
   echo "files exist"
else
   echo "files do not exist"

fi
```

Adding `!` cannot work for me.

Comment: Send all error messages to `/dev/null` (the bit bucket) Invert with `if [ ! .... ]`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks a lot. Can you please answer this question ?

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up.

Comment: Don't use square-brackets around a command; they're for test expressions. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110).

Comment: The canonical may be *[How can I negate the return-value of a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367069/)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression:

```
if [ adb shell ls ${test_dir}  2> /dev/null ]
```

The redirection `2> /dev/null` redirects any message on `stderr` (any error resulting from `abd shell ls ${test_dir}` to `/dev/null` quaintly known as the `bit bucket`. In essence the bit bucket is a system device node that goes nowhere. So you can copy or redirect any output you like to `/dev/null` and it simply goes away (meaning it isn't copied anywhere and isn't redirected any further -- it just goes into the bit bucket -- a black-hole for convenience) This has the effect of suppressing any output from the test itself.

The second part of your question asks how to negate (invert) a test clause. The simple answer is to put a `'!'` at the front of the test.

Let me know if you have further questions.

---

After further discussion and sorting out that `adb` is a android tool, the solution was to simply check the return following the execution of the command itself, e.g.

```
$ adb shell ls ${test_dir}  2> /dev/null
```

and then test the return with

```
if [ "$?" -ne '0' ]; then 
    # handle error
fi
```

If you have further questions on this issue, just let me know.

Comment: `if [ ! adb shell ls ${test_dir}  2> /dev/null ] ` ? But it does not work for me.

Comment: Let me look at your link further. `abd` isn't a bash command or test. What you want if you are testing for an empty directory is: `[ -z "$(ls -A "$test_dir")" ]` If you want to know if it has file, then `[ "$(ls -A "$test_dir" | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]`.

Comment: That's OK, my eyes are crossing as I get older `:)`. Were you testing for files in a directory, or for an empty dir?

Comment: I want to check dir exists. It's my fault and I will update my question.

Comment: If you want to test that a directory exists, then use `if [ -d "$dirname" ]; then echo "$direname exists"; else echo "$dirname not found"; fi` You can also just check `if [ ! -d "$dirname" ]; then echo "$dirname doesn't exist"; fi`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169523/discussion-between-coxier-and-david-c-rankin).