# How to judge pipeline output?

Tags: shell, grep

I have the following command, like:

```
command1 | grep "xxxx"
```

`command1` will output some line text.

I hope that execute `exit 1` when the line includes `xxxx`, or output the line to console, like:

```
command1 | if [ grep "xxxx" ] then; exit 1; else echo;
```

How should I write the shell? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to test the exit status of `grep`, and you want to see the line if it does not contain `xxxx`, you can adapt the following code to suit our requirements (where I'm using `echo "$line"` as a surrogate for your `command1`, and I'm echoing `exit 1` rather than actually exiting when your code would execute `exit 1`):

```
for line in 'hello xxxx here' 'hello yyyy here'
do
    if ! echo "$line" | grep -v 'xxxx'
    then echo "exit 1"
    fi
done
```

The output is:

```
exit 1
hello yyyy here
```

See [How can I negate the return value of a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367069/how-can-i-negate-the-return-value-of-a-process/367167#367167) for a discussion of the `!` operator in POSIX shells (such as Bash).

Since you don't want to see the output when it contains `xxxx` but do otherwise, the `-v` option to `grep` inverts the logic, only printing lines that do not match `xxxx`.  The status of `grep -v 'xxxx'` is 0 when it only finds lines that don't match `xxxx`, and `1` if it finds a line that matches.  The `!` operator inverts this status, and the `if` tests whether the inverted status is 0, executing the `then` code if the inverted status is 0.

Note that `[` is just a command that returns a suitable exit status which the `if` tests.  On many systems, you can find `/bin/[` as an executable, maybe as a (symbolic?) link to `/bin/test` — but modern shells invariably treat `[` and `test` as built-in commands.  Note that `[` checks that its last argument is `]` and objects if it isn't; `test` does not.